# Fresh installation of Magento 2 - store loads fine, admin login fails with CURLPROTO_HTTP error

Tags: magento2, admin-panel

Fresh Magento2 manual installation on Ubuntu 16.04. Store with samples displays fine. Admin page with user and password displays fine too.

Once credentials are entered and trying to login, getting

> There has been an error processing your request error on page and "Error log record number: 714486746083".

In the `log/report` folder of my Magento installation, I can see the error:

> {"0":"Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLPROTO_HTTP - assumed 'CURLPROTO_HTTP' in /var/www/myserverexample.com/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 50","1".."

I checked:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
php7.1-curl is already the newest version (7.1.18-1+ubuntu16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 299 not upgraded
```

Permissions:
[image: magento folder screenshot]
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install php-common php-cli php-curl php-intl php-zip -y` *
3. `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

*It's a bit of a shotgun fix installing so many packages at once, but it saves messing about.

Ref: [How to set up a web server for Magento 2.2 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://digitalstartup.co.uk/magento/set-up-web-server-for-magento-2/)

Comment: Thank you, I followed this, but I get the same error.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what PHP version are you running? (`php -v`)

Comment: P.S. I've updated my answer. From what I've seen, there was a bug relating to this type of error many years ago. I've added an initial step to update the OS packages. Not sure if that will help to be honest.

Comment: PHP 7.2.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jun 22 2018 08:44:50) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Not sure if it really matters, but M2 Requirements for PHP only go up to 7.1.x (Ref: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html). Other than that, I'm stumped. Sorry. If you do figure it out, please let us know.